# Using Arrays in Singleton Class to Pass Data Between View Controllers IOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, singleton, nsarray

I have been searching for tableviews and singleton classes but could not find any solution so here I am.

I have a table view in a viewcontroller when user selects a row I want to send the selected data to an array in singleton class and  print it to screen in another viewcontroller.

Here is my Singleton Class code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface DataController : NSObject {
    NSArray* standLoc;
}

@property (readonly)NSArray* standLoc; // stand location 

+(DataController*)sharedInstance;

@end


#import "DataController.h"

@implementation DataController

@synthesize standLoc;

+(DataController*)sharedInstance
{
    static DataController* sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance)
    {
        sharedInstance = [[DataController alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

So how do Should I pass the data to the Array in the  Singleton Class I tried following,

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    StartHuntViewController *startHuntController = [[StartHuntViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartHuntView" bundle:nil];

    DataController* sharedSingleton = [DataController sharedInstance];
    sharedSingleton = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    startHuntController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:startHuntController animated:YES];;


    [startHuntController release];
    startHuntController =nil;
}
```

In debug I can see selected item is in sharedSingleton but how can I pass it to NSArray* standLoc?

**EDIT**

---

SO i have edited my code and it works fine fow multiple contorller views right now

my Singleton .m and .h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface DataController : NSObject {
    NSString* standLoc;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString* standLoc; // stand location 

+(DataController*)sharedInstance;
-(void) setData: (NSString *) data;

@end
#import "DataController.h"


@implementation DataController


static DataController* sharedInstance = nil;

@synthesize standLoc;

+(DataController*)sharedInstance
{

    @synchronized (self) { //this ensure this methods will not be called at the same time..
        if(sharedInstance == nil){
            [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
+(id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    @synchronized (self){
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedInstance;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{ // incase if we want to copy our singleton instance
    return self;
}
//to protect singleton from deallocation, we need to override some functions of memory allocation
-(id) retain {
    return self;
}

-(id) autorelease{
    return self;
}
-(NSUInteger ) retainCount{
    return NSUIntegerMax;
}

-(id) init{ // lets set the default data in it
    @synchronized (self){
        [super init];
        standLoc = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Stand Loc"];//for performance, as we expect 5 digits from server, it's size was set to another 5 digits..
        return self;
    }
}
-(void) setData: (NSString *) data{ // this is the function to set static data which is the member of the class, reaching data will be allowed with this method
    @synchronized (self){
        if (standLoc != data) {
            [standLoc release];
            standLoc = [data retain];
        }
    }
}
-(NSString *) standLoc{
    @synchronized(self){
        return standLoc;
    }
}
```

to pass data to singleton :

```
DataController* sharedSingleton = [DataController sharedInstance];
    NSString* transfer = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [sharedSingleton setData:transfer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't make standLoc readonly if you want to update it from other classes.
- Why do you want standLoc to be an array if you're going to pass it one object out of 'stands'?
- The kind of syntax you want (after settling the above two points) is:

  DataController* sharedSingleton = [DataController sharedInstance];

  sharedSingleton.standLoc = // Whatever the data element is that should be in the singleton;

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the singleton? Your code will be simpler and easier to maintain if you simply pass the data directly from one view controller to the next. It sounds like you're using a navigation controller so that when a cell in your table is tapped, the table's view controller can push a new detail controller, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.data = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: problem is i have multiple viewcontrollers not just two, If I pass data to main view from any of the views and navigate to another viewcontroller and then comeback to main again, I see that data has been lost, so I needed a solution for keeping data in my main viewcontroller so I thought singleton pattern is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are You using @ synchronized?

(it's very rarely used on iOS..) 
Anyway if You are using (nonatomic) and then @synchronized, it seems a bit odd..

So let's Apple compiler do its job better:

(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

> Properties Are Atomic by Default By default, an Objective-C property
>   is atomic:
>
> @interface XYZObject : NSObject @property NSObject
>   *implicitAtomicObject;          // atomic by default @property (atomic) NSObject *explicitAtomicObject; // explicitly marked atomic
>   @end This means that the synthesized accessors ensure that a value is
>   always fully retrieved by the getter method or fully set via the
>   setter method, even if the accessors are called simultaneously from
>   different threads.

last note: as Apple says, using lock, atomic and so on, does NOT guarantee against deep access to data form different threads:

if You have an array and you protect it (its reference..) with atomic/synchronized, you protect access to it, NOT to contained objects.
(You will have to lock by hand with a lot of care... race conditions can happen...)